# Français relâché lors des diapos

Tags: présentation, français-relâché

Je me demande quelles règles du français pourraient être relâchées lors de la préparation des diapositives pour que le texte soit plus concis.

Par exemple : quant à l'usage des articles ou des pronoms, peut-on les enlever  ?

Quant aux accords quelles règles sont vraiment indispensables et desquelles le respect est moins élastique ?

Un exemple pragmatique :

> Ils restent quelques cas particuliers.

peut devenir

> Restent quelques cas particuliers.

ou même

> Reste quelques cas particuliers.

Évidement je cherche d'autres astuces.

Comment: Ce n'est pas une question de français, mais d'art de la présentation. Les diapositives ne devraient être là que pour soutenir un discours construit délivré à l'oral et étayé par un rapport écrit. Quelques exemples chez [TED Talks](https://www.ted.com/talks?language=fr). Quant à l'exemple, je suggère simplement _Cas particuliers_, le discours est là pour ajouter les mots manquants.

Comment: Étant donné que le français n'est pas ma langue maternelle je cherche à garder une équilibre entre un texte quelque peu "laconique" et un texte qui va faciliter mon discours. D'où cette question concernant le soit-disant français relâché. Je vous remercie vivement de votre commentaire très utile quand même.

Comment: Prénoms ou pronoms ? Les pronoms, c'est dur de les enlever sans que le texte devienne incompréhensible.

Comment: Faute de frappe:-) Je m'excuse @StéphaneGimenez : Oui, bien sûr je voulais dire pronoms. Je me trombe tantôt avec le couple prénom-pronom tantôt avec préposition-proposition...

Comment: et le couple trombe-trompe ;-) Attention aussi à l'utilisation de *soi-disant* (sans t à **soi**) qui est controversé quand on l'applique à une chose (et non une personne) et qui est péjoratif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comme dis dans les commentaires mettre "Cas particuliers" peut être suffisant dans une diapositive.
Par contre

> Ils restent quelques cas particuliers.

ou

> Restent quelques cas particuliers.

Me parait faux. Reste doit être au singulier.
Dans cette utilisation ce sera toujours du singulier.

> Il reste du travail à faire.
>
> Il reste à manger.
>
> Il reste des devoir.

Ce serait au pluriel avec la tournure :

> Quelques cas particulier restent.

(Désolé c'est un peu hors sujet)

Comment: *Ils restent quelques cas particuliers* est incorrect car le pronom *il* doit rester impersonnel (donc singulier), mais la forme plurielle avec sujet postposé ***restent quelques cas particuliers*** est parfaitement correcte et même la règle. Le singulier est néanmoins possible en considérant qu'il y a ellipse du pronom *il*. – jlliagre 9 hours ago

Comment: Comme l'explique @jlliagre, cette réponse est fause.